# Substance that can change your physical form

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, science-fiction

I had a dream, or rather a nightmare about a man that was a scientist that experimented with new types of drugs on himself. He became unhinged and began to kill random people and hide their bodies in an indoor swimming pool in his house.

A man he knew offered him a completely new kind of drug that he hasn't tried before. He goes home and takes the drug and then rapidly metamorphosis into a monster that looks like a cross between a man and a giant lamprey, except with bigger teeth. His arms and legs also transform into tentacles with the same kind of triangular teeth in his mouth. The teeth resemble those from a giant shark. He then attacks his wife and engulfs her with the tentacles. The teeth are shredding through her flesh at this point. With his last act of humanity, he tries to bite off his tentacle, but it doesn't work. He then eats her whole.

Would it possible for some kind of drug or substance that could completely change your genetics and make you turn into some kind of inhuman creature?

**EDIT:** The answer does not need to be based on current technology. This would be based on the technology available 50 years from now.

Comment: District 9's prawn DNA canister?

Comment: Sluggy's Squid Spear

Comment: God. Almighty. I can't believe what I just read. I wouldn't want to have your dreams :-P

Comment: Your dreams are actually worse than mine are. I mean, fleeing government forces in a forest with friends and family getting shot is not as bad as watching an insane serial killer rip apart humans.

Comment: Most drugs are not that bad...

Comment: That's a drug that wont make any money on the street....

Answer (score 4):

With our current technology level and understanding of genetics/proteomix, no it is impossible. Funnily enough, most of the genetic changes a person goes through during his/her life do not change his/her attributes but are visible in his/her offsprings. The people who took the horrible dose of american atomic bombs in Hiroshima and Nagasaki and yet survived, did not undergo any physical change (resulting from genetic mutation) themselves, but their children were born crippled and malformed.

So no. While you CAN change the attributes of your offsprings by changing your DNA, you cannot change your own, once you have fully grown and matured.

Answer (score 1):

No.

To be more specific, no single substance could have such drastic but controlled effects, at the very least you're talking some sort of viral particle with new DNA to inject into your system.

Just changing the DNA is not enough though, your body needs time and a lot of it to regrow into the new configuration. Assuming someone managed to package all the information needed to complete the transformation to the final form while staying alive then you're still taking a long time (weeks at least) for the transformation to happen.

The moral of the tale? Don't take drugs from strangers...

Answer (score 1):

Um, no.  Anything that messed with your DNA that much would likely kill you leaving you in a pile of goo.

The most likely thing would be a virus probably one designed specifically for a specific transformation.

Comment: It was given to him as a punishment. It was specifically designed to do exactly what it did. He just was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

DNA does not actually work that way.  Think of a shop floor with a foreman high above the floor holding a megaphone.  This foreman's the DNA.  He can shout instructions (information) down from on high, telling the structures and proteins on the shop floor what to do.  He can tell some of the enforcer-like structures to remove offending workers who are disrupting his goals, but he has no actual power.  It is the workers doing all the work, and they regularly communicate between eachother.

To make the workers radically change what they are doing by injecting new DNA is very difficult.  If you've ever tried to get a bunch of employees to stay in sync, it's a lot harder than just barking orders.  You have to be subtle.  **The best leaders are the ones who listen to what the employees have to say, and help accentuate the parts of that message which fit well with where the leader wants to go.**

This is the challenge.  How do you make such a DNA seurum.  What is the magic message the foreman can start barking to get all of the workers to suddenly stop making what they're doing, and focus on sharkfin soup and caviar.  You would have to listen to what all the cells in this man's body are saying on the shop floor to determine the message for the DNA to shout.

Now you're looking for a reality-check, but there's some pretty decent escape-from-reality feel to it, so I'd like to offer an alternative.  I would not call it valid science, but I think it's interesting enough that you might get people to accept the handwaving.  Consider that something made this man what he is.  It is most likely a combination of nature and nurture.  Something isn't *ideal* in his DNA, and something in his environment probably upregulated that.  Maybe he was dropped when he was a child, and some of the important workers in his skull stopped doing work.  The body is flexible.  Other workers will try to pick up the work.  Eventually some may start dissiminating information across the shop floor suggesting particular ideas coming from the foreman that shouldn't be listened to.

What if your DNA serum, instead of *causing* all of these changes, merely unlocked the deep dark dirty parts of the man's DNA, and provided it a few hints as to subliminal messages it could use to start distorting the way the workers think.  You then stand back, and find out what happens as a effect of the seurum.  You don't know for sure, because you're using a very coarse tool, but you know it will do something.  Then it's the workers on the shop floor that start to develop their own dark side, letting out all the bad things they may have been trying to hold onto the whole time.

**Its pure pseudoscience.  There's no scientific reason to believe this would happen.**  But having the entire *essence* of an evil person direct the vile and brutal transformation is far more likely than a mere serum being able to do it.  There are many groups who claim the mind is capable of amazing things.  Who knows, perhaps they're right.